# Can we run rest calls during ARM template deployment like Azure does for App Service Domain?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Can we create ARM template UI definition to mimick this behavior of making rest calls when the text box loses focus in Arm Template Deployment.
Like below
[image]

Comment: You want to do adhoc evaluation of something via REST in an arm template?  What's the scenario?

Comment: That is right. The scenario is to exactly mimic like the App Service Domain - Search for domain field. Have a Text box and do a REST call on focus out and take the input from one of the selected results. As pass that to an ARM template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a dedicated widget for calling Azure 'ARM' APIs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/microsoft-solutions-armapicontrol

The following example shows the schema for this control:

```
{
    "name": "testApi",
    "type": "Microsoft.Solutions.ArmApiControl",
    "request": {
        "method": "{HTTP-method}",
        "path": "{path-for-the-URL}",
        "body": {
            "key1": "val1",
            "key2": "val2"
        }
    }
}
```

But there is not a way to just call generic rest endpoints.